# Where to fetch and send data in a very nested component tree

Tags: javascript, reactjs, redux, react-redux

I my app I want users to be able to comment and like a post. So I created a component tree with the following structure

- Top Component

  - View component

    - TopBar
    - Body

      - Author card
      - Post card
      - Comment sec
      - Floating like button component

When you load the top component fetches the data. While it fetches the body component will show a pre-loader.  After fetching, it sends the Data to (user_data) view -> topbar and (post_data) view -> body.  Everything works OK till when I try to comment. The comment component sends the comment to body -> view -> top. And after re-render it shows the pre-loader again. This also happens when I click the like button. So is their a way to avoid this? Thank in advance

EDIT:

Top component add comment: data from Comment component

```
addComment = data => {
        this.props.add_comment(data).then(
            () => {
                this.props.fetch_data();
                if (this.props.isLoggedIn) {
                    this.props.fetch_user_data();
                }
            }
        );
    }
```

mapStateToDispatch:

```
const mapDispatchToProps = dispatch => {
    return {
        // recieve data
        fetch_user_data: () => dispatch(fetch_user_data()),

        // upload data
        add_comment: data => dispatch(add_comment(data)),
        reply_comment: data => dispatch(reply_comment(data))
    };
};
```

redux-action:

```
export const add_comment = data => {
    return dispatch => {
        dispatch(sendComment());

        const headers = {
            method: 'POST',
            body: JSON.stringify({ query: mutations.create_comment(data) }),
            headers: {
                'Content-Type': 'application/json'
            }
        };

        return fetch('http://192.168.43.200:5000/graphql', headers).then(
            res => {
                dispatch(requestCommentFinished());
                return res.json();
            }
        );
    };
};
```

requestCommentFinished reducer:

```
const requestCommentFinished = state => {
    const isSendingComment = false;
    return updateObject(state, {
        isSendingComment
    });
};
```

Comment: Hmm, can you post some code? You might be updating `state` at the top level incorrectly.

Comment: agree with @Colin.
you are not using the state/props correctly, because your render is triggering in a top level component.

Comment: If only the one data change won't it trigger a top component render?

Comment: I just edited the question including more code. If there's anything more I should add please tell me